# Using python Regex to extract content from rss feeds

Tags: python, regex, rss, extract

I'm trying to use regular expressions and specifically the re module to exctract titles, dates and content from rss feeds. So far i've used the following code:

```
    titles = re.findall(r'<title>(.*?)</title>',html_code)
    descriptions = re.findall(r'<description>(.*?)</description>',html_code)   
    dates = re.findall(r'<pubDate>(.*?)</pubDate>',html_code)

    for title in titles:
        if 'The Guardian' in title:
            pass
        else:
            print "Headline:" ,title
            print


    for description in descriptions:
        if 'Latest news and features from theguardian.com' in description:
            pass
        else:
            print "Description:" ,description
            print

    for date in dates:
        print "Date:" ,date
        print
```

This code gives the following output:

```
Headline: Tim Bresnan denies involvement in Kevin Pietersen parody Twitter account

Description: I 100% did NOT have any password, and wasnt involved&lt;br /&gt; ECB confirms Alec Stewart reported incident in 2012 &lt;br /&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.theguardian.com/sport/2014/oct/08/kevin-pietersen-parody-twitter-account-author-denies-england-players-involved" title=""&gt; Twitter account author denies players were involved&lt;/a&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.theguardian.com/sport/blog/2014/oct/08/ecb-england-cricket-kevin-pietersen-tom-harrison" title=""&gt; Owen Gibson: ECB at crossroads amid fallout&lt;/a&gt;&lt;p&gt;Tim Bresnan has denied having any involvement in the controversial @KPgenius Twitter account after Kevin Pietersens autobiography claimed his former England team-mates were behind it.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;In his book, Pietersen revealed the extent to which the account had angered and upset him, and claimed that the accounts author had told the former England wicketkeeper Alec Stewart that some of the guys in the dressing room are tweeting from it.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Disappointed to be implicated in the &lt;a href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/kpgenius?src=hash"&gt;#kpgenius&lt;/a&gt; account. I 100% did NOT have any password. And wasn't involved In any posting.&lt;/p&gt; &lt;a href="http://www.theguardian.com/sport/2014/oct/09/tim-bresnan-kevin-pietersen-parody-twitter"&gt;Continue reading...&lt;/a&gt;           

Date: Thu, 09 Oct 2014 11:56:43 GMT
```

These results are printed for each news article. My question was, how do i go about cleaning up the content section and removing all the html junk? I just need some of the basic information of the article without all the tags. How could i use regular expressions to remove these (e.g the links, and ".& lt ;/p&gt ;") ? Thankyou

Comment: Probably you are better off using an XML parser - `xml.etree.ElementTree` or `lxml` or similar.

Comment: I'm just trying to use regular expressions without any other modules at the moment

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) to replace the special HTML characters with whatever you need to replace them with.